# Regular expressions, can I exclude pairs of characters?

Tags: regex

How do you exclude pairs of characters from a regular expression?

I am trying to get a regular expression that will have 5 alphanumeric characters followed by

anything except "XX" and "AD", followed by XX.

So

```
D22D0ACXX
```

will match, but the following two will not match

```
D22D0ADXX   
D22D0XXXX.
```

My first attempt was :

```
([A-Z0-9]{5}[^(?AD)|(?XX)]XX)
```

But this treats the character classes part [^(?AD)|(?XX)] as one character, so I end up with the last 8 characters, not all 9.

Can I exclude pairs of characters without getting into back references?

I need to capture the whole group, hence the outer parenthesis. The negative lookahead suggestions don't seem to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
([A-Z0-9]{5}(?!(AD|XX)XX).{4})
```

Comment: I should have added that I need to capture the whole group, which this doesn't seem to do.

Comment: @wobbily_col: The whole group IS captured, in group 1.

Comment: "D22D0" is all that my python script is capturing.

Try it here: 
http://regex101.com/#python

Comment: @wobbily_col: did you use exactly the regex as mentionned with the parenthesis at the right place? The group 1 includes the whole match. The first part (ie. the five first chars) is not captured in any group.

Comment: yes, I cut and pasted it into my script, and into the online regex tester.

Comment: @wobbily_col: To capture the whole thing, you could add `.{4}` before the last closing parantheses. The regex as stated will not capture the "ACXX" part.

Comment: Thanks Jens, that works. I'll need to read a bit more about how it works though.

Comment: Can you explain how the .{4} works. I know that it usually repeats a character, but what exactly is this repeating?

Comment: @wobbily_col: It says there are 4 chars after the first 5. The lookahead doesn't consume character.

Comment: I get it now .{4} matches any 4 characters, but is distinct from the lookahead - which confirms what the next 4 characters are (but doesn't capture them).

Answer (score 1):

Don't treat it as a character class, instead, think of it as an alternation with a negative lookahead, e.g:

```
([A-Z0-9]{5}(?!(AD|XX)XX))
```

Then, if you need the tail, include it after the lookhead, e.g:

```
([A-Z0-9]{5}(?!(AD|XX)XX)[A-Z0-9]{4})
```