# Exclude sequences of characters (not only single characters) inside a regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have expressions with this form...

```
@@name<·parameters·>
```

...and I want a regular expression that matches the groups `name` and `parameters`. As I have a closed (and small) group of values for `name` I preffer to use a for loop to try with all the few values, but `parameters` can be anything... anything except `<·` and `·>`, wich are the sequences for opening and closing sets of parameters.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380759/regular-expressions-can-i-exclude-pairs-of-characters) and I tried this...

```
@@(name)<·((?!(<·|·>).*))·>
```

...but I can't get it working. I think that the reason is that there the excluded expression is known in position and in number of repetitions (1) but in my case I want to exclude every occurrence of any of this two sequences in a string of unknown length.

Do you know how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: *"use a for bucle to try"* - what?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: bucle = loop in español.

Comment: why complicate things? if you already know that parameters is going to be inside of a `<· and ·>` then you dont need the lookaround to achieve your result. `@@(name)<·(.*)·>` works fine!

Comment: oh, it seems like a unicode dot.

Comment: @RNar because with `(.*)` the expression would match everything, including `<·` and `·>`.

Comment: not if you have the `<·` and `·>` tokens wrapping around the `(.*)` token like above. as long as you are accessing group 2, it will not include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You regex must be,

```
@@(name)<·((?:(?!<·|·>).)*)·>
```

Negative lookahead method. Just understand this part `(?!<·|·>).` only which matches any character(*dot*) but not of `<·` or `·>` , `(?:(?!<·|·>).)*` zero (*star*) or more times.

or

Non-greedy method.

```
@@(name)<·(.*?)·>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nH4nD3/3)

Comment: Thank you. It works and now I understand it. But why the "non-greedy" method it's supposed to work?

Comment: Why the non-greedy method won't work? `.*?` matches any character zero or more times non-greedily.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following regex:

```
@@([^<]*)<\·([^\·]+)\·>
```